# SQL query not functioning well

Tags: php, mysql

In [my php](http://eclash.tk/code.txt) when $sql is echoed returns

```
INSERT INTO players (tag,link) VALUES 
('SUCHE','https\:\/\/www\.clashofstats\.com\/players\/SUCHE/') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE link='https\:\/\/www\.clashofstats\.com\/players\/SUCHE/'
```

BUT in table its being entered as `tag` value as **SUCHE** and `link` value as **SUCHE/**

I am unable to understand my mistake.
On re entering the same tag the link gets updated properly which means the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE link='".$linkF."/'` is working fine.
[Image of database ,row showing link are inserted via desktop browser via those not are from chrome mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsJQt.png)
**Crucial Update:** Working fine in Mozilla Browser(Desktop and mobile) , Not working just in Chrome Android.

**Is it a Chrome App Bug?** if so then please help me to bypass it

Thanx

Comment: the issue occurs in Chrome Android, but not on CHrome Desktop

Comment: Are you using single quote in wrapping that query?

Comment: Show us the `SHOW CREATE TABLE players` output and some example data (text table not a image) and edit that output and example data in the question

Comment: @Swellar Double quotes     
  $sql1 = "INSERT INTO players (tag,link) VALUES ('".$tagTOup."','".$linkF."/') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE link='".$linkF."/'";

Comment: Can you check the value of $linkF

Comment: @NigelRen    echo $linkF gives `http\:\/\/www\.coc\-stats\.net\/en\/player\/SUCHE`